# Regex performance: validating alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, performance

When trying to validate that a string is made up of alphabetic characters only, two possible regex solutions come to my mind.

The first one checks that every character in the string is alphanumeric:

```
/^[a-z]+$/
```

The second one tries to find a character somewhere in the string that is **not** alphanumeric:

```
/[^a-z]/
```

*(Yes, I could use character classes here.)*

Is there any significant performance difference for long strings?
(If anything, I'd guess the second variant is faster.)

Comment: Wy don't you test it?  Create some large data sets (or import some from somewhere), build the script, and time 100 iterations or similar.

Comment: Why the capture in the first regex?

Comment: Hmm, good question. I copy-pasted the capture group, that wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just by looking at it, I'd say the second method is faster.

However, I made a quick non-scientific test, and the results seem to be inconclusive:

**[Regex Match vs. Negation](http://jsperf.com/regex-match-vs-negation)**.

---

**P.S.** I removed the group capture from the first method. It's superfluous, and would only slow it down.

Comment: Heh, why the `';'` character in the tested string? Don't we need valid input?

Comment: @owlstead - Correct. I added tests for both (pass/fail), and the results seem to vary on a per-browser basis.

Comment: BTW, can anybody explain to me what sort of witchcraft Opera employs to get such results?

Comment: Thanks for the testing. Sorry about the group capture, that was my mistake.

Comment: Seems to me that it does not make a whole lot of difference for the pass scenario. In that case I would go for the regexp that matches all the characters, as it is more clear. The other one requires a double negation to get a positive result.

Comment: That said, you can use the other to retrieve the first non-matching character, which you may use to create a better error condition (character #i with value $c is not alphanumeric). Hmm. Whichever is your cup of tea, I guess :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrote this quick Perl code:

```
    @testStrings = qw(asdfasdf asdf as aa asdf as8up98;n;kjh8y  puh89uasdf ;lkjoij44lj 'aks;nasf na ;aoij08u4 43[40tj340ij3 ;salkjaf;  a;lkjaf0d8fua ;alsf;alkj   
a a;lkf;alkfa as;ldnfa;ofn08h[ijo ok;ln n ;lasdfa9j34otj3;oijt 04j3ojr3;o4j ;oijr;o3n4f;o23n a;jfo;ie;o ;oaijfoia ;aosijf;oaij ;oijf;oiwj; 
qoeij;qwj;ofqjf08jf0 ;jfqo;j;3oj4;oijt3ojtq;o4ijq;onnq;ou4f ;ojfoqn;aonfaoneo ;oef;oiaj;j a;oefij iiiii iiiiiiiii iiiiiiiiiii); 


    print "test 1: \n";
    foreach my $i (1..1000000) {
            foreach (@testStrings) {
                    if ($_ =~ /^([a-z])+$/) {
                            #print "match"
                    } else {
                            #print "not"
                    }
            }
    }

    print `date` . "\n";

    print "test 2: \n";
    foreach my $j (1..1000000) {
            foreach (@testStrings) {
                    if ($_ =~ /[^a-z]/) {
                            #print "match"
                    } else {
                            #print "not"
                    }
            }
    }
```

then ran it with:
date; <perl_file>; date

it isn't 100% scientific, but it gives us a good idea. The first Regex took 10 or 11 seconds to execute, the second Regex took 8 seconds.

Comment: You should remove the group capture from the first regex.

Comment: I noticed it, but didn't originally remove it so I'd run the Regex EXACTLY as asked. However, I went ahead and removed it and it didn't make any difference in the times (I ran these tests about 10 times)

Comment: You should record the pass/fail instances separately. They're quite different.

Comment: Thanks for the testing. Sorry about the group capture, that was my mistake.

Comment: The group capture normally does not make much of a difference; it amounts to storing indexes to the string (at least if the string itself is mutable, as is the fact in Java). Even if you retrieve the matching group, it's likely to still point to the same memory location (again, if this reacts as in Java).